# Can someone help me with bootstrap / grid

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have different size pictures in my grid boxes.

```
<div class="page-header">
  <h1><img src="logo2.png" width="1047" height="101" alt="logo" longdesc="http://tvt.tyovoimalasaatio.fi"></a></h1>
</div>
```

Here is the [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4g44S/1/)

Which looks like the following screen

[image]

How can i get those 3x/line and to each others ?

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-3">
    <img class="img-responsive" src="">
</div>

<div class="col-md-3">
    <img class="img-responsive" src="">
</div>

<div class="col-md-3">
    <img class="img-responsive" src="">
</div>
</div>
```

That is the basic template for image, you can put
    min-height: 100px;
or like that for the div to make them equal. Or, you can use
    padding: .
Basically, put 3 images in an row, and col-md-3 for each div, so you will have enough space for an image as well as designing, margin, padding etc